# Вывод элементов массива в определённом порядке

Tags: php, foreach

Есть код

```
<?php
$arr = array('green'=>'зеленый', 'red'=>'красный','blue'=>'голубой');
  foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {
  echo $key . "<br>";
  }

  foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {
  echo $value . "<br>";

}
?>
```

Как вывести элементы в том же порядке, но реализовать это в одном цикле foreach?

Comment: для обхода массивов удобна функция array_walk. к тому же в документации уже приведен пример, похожий на вашу задачу: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$keys = $values = "";
foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {
    $keys   .= $key . "<br>";
    $values .= $value . "<br>";
}

echo $keys, $values;
```

Можно и без foreach:

```
echo implode("<br>", array_keys($arr));
echo "<br>";
echo implode("<br>", array_values($arr));
echo "<br>";
```